# Rails deployment on Two servers with asset_sync : Assets unavailable on the second server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to deploy a rails 3.2.12 app on two different servers, behind an nginx powered load balancer.

I'm using asset_sync to deploy the assets to S3 and Capistrano.

When the deployment is done, everything works great on the first server, but on the second one I get the following error:

```
A ActionView::Template::Error occurred in home#index:

  application.css isn't precompiled
  actionpack (3.2.12) lib/sprockets/helpers/rails_helper.rb:142:in `digest_for'
```

I've noticed that during the deployment, deploy:assets:precompile is only execute on the first server. But that seems expected to me.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do both servers have a public/assets/manifest.yml file?

Comment: I can find in on the first server. The second one, the one bugging doesn't even have a public/assets directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what my stupid mistake was. I only listed the two servers in the web role.

```
role :web, "server1"
role :app, "server1", "server2"
```

When I declared both servers, it worked fine.

```
role :web, "server1", "server2"
role :app, "server1", "server2"
```

Comment: You can also set which server roles the asset compilation task will run on instead of changing which servers have which role: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/issues/128

Comment: Isn't it a waste to run the asset compilation on both servers, if are serving all assets from S3 anyway?